# XPath for href link

Tags: html, xml, xpath, href

I got for example

```
<a href="target.php">News</a>
<a href="more.php">More</a>
```

What would be the most efficient way of extracting the `href` based on the value between `<a></a>` (the atomic data) with XPath

Comment: `//a/@href`. what does *based on the value between* mean ?

Comment: *on the value between* - you mean select `href` attribute by node value?

Comment: `//a[.='News']/@href`

Answer (score 9):

Question interpretation:

- "Most efficient" is taken to mean in a programmer's time sense, not
  in a performance sense.
- "The value between" is taken to mean the string between the `a` tags.

This XPath selects all `a` elements,

```
//a
```

This XPath selects all `a` elements whose string value is `"News"`:

```
//a[.='News']
```

This XPath selects all `href` attributes of all `a` elements whose string value is `"News"`<sup>1</sup>:

```
//a[.='News']/@href
```

<sub><sup>1. Credit: [@localghost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5847556/localghost) posted correct answer in comments</sup></sub>